# How to render dom components in reagent asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, clojurescript, reagent

I make an http request and try to put the returned val into a reagent component like so:

```
[div
    (a/take! (http/get "http://localhost:5000/data"))
             #(into [:div]
                     (map render-method
                          (into [] (map (fn [res] (:name res)) (-> % :body :results))))

                     )
                )
]
```

But this understandably doesn't work because the a/take! itself doesn't return the component. So how does one make the async get request work with reagent?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Instead you need to store the result in an atom, and reagent will rerender for you once it's loaded.

```
(def data (reagent/atom nil))

(defn fetch-data []
  (take! (http/get "http://localhost:5000/data") #(reset! data %)))

(defn names-list []
  [:div
   (doall (map :name @data))])

(defn my-component []
  [:div
   (if @data
     [names-list]
     [:div "loading"])])
```